# No longer getting notifcation of facebook comments

Tags: facebook

I have two commenting apps that work fine from the user perspective. 
However, even though I am a moderator on both I no longer receive notifications when someone has commented. I used to get something like "John Doe has commented on your site, xxx".
There are no changes I know of in either my notification settings nor in the app.
Is there no more automatic notification to moderators?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and have been unable to find a solution. In my case, when people reply to an existing comment I DO get a notification, but not for the original comment.